# Django, CBVs and pk_url_kwarg is missing

Tags: django

I am learning django.  I have the latest django and Python 3.7.x.

I have a question about `self.pk_url_kwarg` and how it is created and when.  I have seen the doc at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/ but am not finding the answer I hope for.

Specifically, I have an entry in a `url.py` file like:

```
...
path(
    'Student/createFromProfile/<uuid:profile_id>',
    student.CreateFromProfile.as_view(),
    name="student_create_from_profile"
),
...
```

I have a CBV for this that starts:

```
@method_decorator(verified_email_required, name='dispatch')
class CreateFromProfile(CreateView):

    model = Profile
    success_url = '/Members'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            account_holder = Profile.objects.get(
                id=self.kwargs["profile_id"]
            )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.error(
                request,
                "Unknown Profile ID."
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

Notice in the `get` method the `try` and the section `id=self.kwargs["profile_id"]`.  I was trying to use `id=self.kwargs[self.pk_url_kwarg]` but I get a django debug page that says that it has no idea what `pk_url_kwarg` is.  I can stop in the PyCharm debugger and inspect `self` and indeed, it has no entry for `pk_url_kwarg`.  This is extra special strange because I am using this in other views.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pk_url_kwarg` is the name of the URLConf keyword argument which is `pk` by default. In your particular case you should set it to `profile_id`:

```
@method_decorator(verified_email_required, name='dispatch')
class CreateFromProfile(CreateView):

    model = Profile
    success_url = '/Members'

    # Here we're setting correct pk_url_kwarg
    pk_url_kwarg = 'profile_id'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            account_holder = Profile.objects.get(
                id=self.kwargs[self.pk_url_kwarg]
            )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.error(
                request,
                "Unknown Profile ID."
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

That's because you've specified `<uuid:profile_id>` in your url path.

Second way is to rewrite your url config to be `'Student/createFromProfile/<uuid:pk>'`. This way `pk_url_kwarg` should work with default value.

Comment: I have other CBVs that have similar urls with a named parameter.  Those seem to auto-populate a `self.pk_url_kwarg`.  I can certainly set the value myself.  Thank you.